# Incrementing a Bootstrap Progress Bar with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Trying to figure out how to animate a bootstrap progress bar with increments defined by checked/unchecked checkboxes. I have one checkbox working at a time, but cannot seem to figure out how to get all of them to add to the previous amount.

i.e if I click 2 checkboxes, 40% would be shown on the progress bar, 3 checkboxes 60%, etc. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="panelBody" id="panelBody1">

      <input id="input1" type="checkbox" name="completed1" value="20">
      <input id="input2" type="checkbox" name="completed2" value="20">
      <input id="input3" type="checkbox" name="completed3" value="20">
      <input id="input4" type="checkbox" name="completed4" value="20">
      <input id="input5" type="checkbox" name="completed5" value="20">

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
  var emptyValue = 0;
  $('input:checked').each(function(){
       if ( $(this).attr('value') > emptyValue ) {
           emptyValue =  $(this).attr('value');
       }
  });

  $('.progress-bar').css('width', emptyValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue);

});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the value, try this:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    var emptyValue = 0;
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        emptyValue += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', emptyValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', emptyValue);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Lz7/)